# NGX-Translate on Angular 4, ERROR ON "return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');"

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I have looked for answers over Google and Stackoverflow, but didn't find a solution.

I followed instructions from the [website](https://medium.com/letsboot/translate-angular-4-apps-with-ngx-translate-83302fb6c10d)

My steps:

1) Created an Angular 4 project using `ng new NGXTest`.

2)Inside the project folder, executed:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

3) Added imports:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';`
```

4) Added to `app.module.ts` next line:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

And here is when the problem starts.

[Error in Visual Studio Code, Web executing, and in Git terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yHPF.png)

And if I continue with the tutorial, i get also other errors in Git terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem, and I will explain my mistake.

I followed tutorial from the official website: http://www.ngx-translate.com/

But I didn't do it properly.

There are 2 libraries, which must be installed:
-core
-http-loader

I installed both but didn't include code lines for http-loader.

Following instructions properly is enough, and is not difficult.

**Thanks for all the help. And I am sorry for making you lose time.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json'),
          deps: [Http]
        })
    ],
    exports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, TranslateModule],
})
```

Suppose to work.

Comment: Thanks very much, yesterday I solved the problem, I explain my mistake down.

I gave you a +1 vote, but I dont have reputation yet :D